# Silly compile error using lists / iterators (C++)

Tags: c++, iterator, compiler-errors

The following does not compile, and I cannot for the life of me see why!

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

list<char> myList;
list<int>::iterator it;

it = myList.begin();
```

The error:

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Note that for template-related errors, the Microsoft compiler will print the template parameters in the line after the error message. So the next line will contain something like `with [Ty_ = int] and [Ty_ = char]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `list<char> and list<int>` are two different classes.
So their iterators are different types too.
If you look at std::list class code you will see something like:

```
typedef _Iterator<_SECURE_VALIDATION_DEFAULT> iterator;
```

or

```
typedef _Iterator<bla_bla_bla> iterator;
```

That means new type is defined by each distinct class list. In other words each  list defines its own iterator type.

Change your code to this:

```
list<char>::iterator it;
```

Comment: Agg, I cannot believe I didnt see that :-S

Comment: That usually means you need a short break ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because the type of the iterator is different:

```
list<char> myList; // char
list<int>::iterator it; // int
```

Beware that the type of the list or any other container is not only the **template *type* parameter**, but all other template parameters as well. For example:

```
list<char, MyAllocator> mylist;
list<char, YourAllocator> yourlist;
// typeof mylist != type of yourlist      (!!!)
```